# Convert list to RDD

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to work on a samplecsv.csv file(64 MB) in pyspark.
This code generates an error: **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'**

I think I have already converted list to RDD using parallelize. If not, how is it done?

```
file = sc.textFile('/user/project/samplecsv.csv',5)
rdd = file.map(lambda line: (line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1], 
                             line.split(',')[2], line.split(',')[3], 
                             line.split(',')[4])).collect()
temp = sc.parallelize([rdd], numSlices=50000).collect()
temp.saveAsTextFile("/user/project/newfile.txt")}
```

Comment: don't call `collect()` - it collects the RDD into a local list, which makes your `rdd` and `temp` variables lists and not RDDs (and then you won't need "temp" - no need to collect and then parallelize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you called collect on the parallelized list, returning it back to a normal python list.

Also, you should not be calling collect in each step, unless you're making it for a testing/debugging process. Otherwise you're not taking advantage of the Spark computing model.

```
# loads the file as an rdd 
file = sc.textFile('/user/project/samplecsv.csv',5)
# builds a computation graph
rdd = file.map(lambda line: (line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1], 
                             line.split(',')[2], line.split(',')[3], 
                             line.split(',')[4]))
# saves the rdd to the filesystem
rdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/project/newfile.txt")
```

Also, you can make the code more optimal by spliting the line only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the below code, it will solve your purpose:

```
file = sc.textFile("C://Users/Ravi/Desktop/test.csv",5)
rdd = file.map(lambda line: (line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1], 
                             line.split(',')[2], line.split(',')[3]))
rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("C://Users/Ravi/Desktop/temp")
```

If you want partitioned file, don't use coalesce.